# EXCEPTION: Type 'NativeJavaScriptObject' is not a subtype of expected type 'HttpRequest'

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm playing with heros tutorial from https://github.com/angular-examples/toh-6/tree/master

hero_service.dart

```
@Injectable()
class HeroService {
  static final _headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
  static const _heroesUrl = 'api/heroes'; // URL to web API

  final Client _http;

  HeroService(this._http);

  Future<List<Hero>> getAll() async {
    try {
      final response = await _http.get(_heroesUrl);
      final heroes = (_extractData(response) as List)
          .map((json) => new Hero.fromJson(json))
          .toList();
      return heroes;
    } catch (e) {
      throw _handleError(e);
    }
  }...
```

I inject browserclient in main.dart

```
@GenerateInjector([
  routerProvidersHash, // You can use routerProviders in production
  //const ClassProvider(Client, useClass: InMemoryDataService),
  // Using a real back end?
  // Import 'package:http/browser_client.dart' and change the above to:
     const ClassProvider(Client, useClass: BrowserClient),
])
final InjectorFactory injector = self.injector$Injector;

void main() {
  runApp(ng.AppComponentNgFactory, createInjector: injector);
}
```

When calling `_http.get(_heroesUrl)` on the injected `BrowserClient` instance, I get the below exception being thrown. sdk version 2.0.0-dev.55.0

```
EXCEPTION: Exception: Server error; cause: Type 'NativeJavaScriptObject' is not a subtype of expected type 'HttpRequest'.
STACKTRACE: 
packages/$sdk/dev_compiler/amd/dart_sdk.js 4823:29             throw
packages/angular_tour_of_heroes/src/hero_service.ddc.js 32:21  getAll
packages/$sdk/dev_compiler/amd/dart_sdk.js 23502:38            onError
packages/stack_trace/stack_trace.ddc.js 142:98                 <fn>.dart.fn
packages/stack_trace/stack_trace.ddc.js 188:16                 [_run]
packages/stack_trace/stack_trace.ddc.js 142:80                 arg
packages/angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.ddc.js 115:18           arg
```

Comment: Please add the code that causes the exception.

Comment: I have tried with the hero's sample and it fails there too.  So I updated my question with that code.

Comment: Is this with Angular 5 and `pub run build_runner serve`?

Comment: Can you please add a link to the hero's sample you tried?

Comment: yes, with Angular 5 and pub run build_runner serve. https://github.com/angular-examples/toh-6/tree/master

Comment: Can you please add how you provide and inject `BrowserClient`

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Perhaps try with an older Dart version (2.0.0-dev.xx.0 with xx lower than 55). I'd create a bug report.

Comment: It sounds like `package:http` has a bug in Dart 2.